# Highstock I wanted to render tooltip for my stock chart in a div outside of the chart svg

Tags: angular, highcharts

[image]

I am using Highstock framework for my angular project. Wanted to render the tooltip outside of my chart container in a div. Here is what I am trying. But Looks like its very very slow to render on screen. One example will be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

In HTML File

```
<p #chartTooltip></p>
```

In .ts file

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
     tooltip: {        
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderWidth: 0,
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function () {
                    return pageInstance.tooltipFormatter( this );
        },

})

tooltipFormatter( pointInfo ) {
    let stringToReturn = ""; 
        let pageInstance = this; 
        stringToReturn = '<div class="chart-tooltip-data-container">'; 
        if( relativeCompare ) {            
            points.map(function (points) {
                let point = points.point;
                stringToReturn += '<div class="chart-tooltip-point" style="color:' + point.color + '">\u25CF</div>'
                stringToReturn += '<span class="chart-tooltip-data"><b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y, 2) + '</b> (' + parseFloat(point.change).toFixed(2) + '%)</span>';
            })
        } else {                  
            points.map(function (points) {
                let point = points.point;
                let pointSeriesType = point.series.options.type; 
                if( !pageInstance.isOverLaySeries( point.series.name ) ) {                
                    if( point.series.name.toLowerCase() != "volume" ){
                        stringToReturn += '<div class="chart-tooltip-point" style="color:' + point.color + '">\u25CF</div> ';
                    }
                    if (pointSeriesType === 'candlestick' || pointSeriesType === 'ohlc') {
                        stringToReturn += '<span class="chart-tooltip-data"> O: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(point.open, 2) + '</span>';
                        stringToReturn += '<span class="chart-tooltip-data"> H: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(point.high, 2) + '</span>';
                        stringToReturn += '<span class="chart-tooltip-data"> L: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(point.low, 2) + '</span>';
                        stringToReturn += '<span class="chart-tooltip-data"> C: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(point.close, 2) + '</span>';
                    } else if ( pointSeriesType === 'column' ){
                        if( point.y != 0 ) {                    
                            stringToReturn += '<span class="chart-tooltip-data"> V: ' + point.y +'</span>';
                        }
                    } else {
                        stringToReturn += '<span class="chart-tooltip-data">' + Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y , 2) + '</span>';
                    }                       
                }
            })           
        }        
        stringToReturn += '</div>';        
        this.setTooltipText( stringToReturn ); 
}

setTooltipText( tooltipText: string ) {             
        if( tooltipText ) {
          this.chartTooltip.nativeElement.innerHTML = tooltipText;                      
        }        
}
```

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor that I could work on?